# Dropmenu get value from the list

Tags: javascript

Hello how can I select the value of Business by using the emplStatus2 GORM object?

```
 <select name="emplStatus2" onchange="swapFieldsets(this.value,     '#sa-email', '#sa-password')" class="form-control" id="emplStatus2">
 <option value="Home">Send via Home Email</option>
 <option value="Business">Send via Business Email</option>
<option value="Password">Set a password now,provide access information      offline</option>
```

Comment: What you trying to do?explain with more bit

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery you can do it like this

`$("#emplStatus2").val("Business")`

if you only want javascript i think its something like this:

`document.getElementById("emplStatus2").options.value = "Business"`

Answer (score 0):

please describe detail what you need.

You can check value

```
function swapFieldsets(elem) {
   if (elem.value.toLowerCase() === 'business') {
     alert(elem.value)
   }
 }
```

On fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xw0pLmod/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select an item using pure javascript, you can use :

```js
SelectOption3();

function SelectOption3() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('select1');
    var val = 'option3';
    for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
        if(sel.options[i].getAttribute("value") === val) {
           sel.selectedIndex = i;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="select1">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
  <option value="option5">option5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
var test = '';
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById("emplStatus2").options.length; i++) {
   if (document.getElementById("emplStatus2").options[i].value === 'Business') {
      test = document.getElementById("emplStatus2").options[i].innerText;
   }
}
alert(test);
```

Here is JsFiddle of your example: https://jsfiddle.net/p457utLL/